# When using an online IDE like gitpod, is there a way to remotely access a server?

Tags: node.js, express, gitpod

Im currently working on a Chromebook with admin blocks on everything, including crosh and Linux dev access. I want to start a server using Express and Node.js, which is functional, but when attempting to connect using a different device, I'm stuck. The IP address the server is relaying is instead Gitpods' IP, not my local IP. Any advice or help is appreciated, and if I'm unclear please let me know so I can change the question or body!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making your server port public from the `Remote Explorer` tab on Gitpod's VSCODE on your Browser?

You can also check this out: https://www.gitpod.io/docs/config-ports#configure-port-visibility